# Why is there no external IP using Contour on Minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I installed contour locally on `minikube version: v1.5.0` with:

```
kubectl apply -f https://projectcontour.io/quickstart/contour.yaml
```

I check the details of the contour ingress controller with:

```
$ kubectl get -n projectcontour service contour -o wide
NAME      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE     SELECTOR
contour   ClusterIP   10.103.81.4   <none>        8001/TCP   4d12h   app=contour
```

Now in the book it says:

> If you are using minikube, you probably won’t have anything listed for
>   EXTERNAL-IP. To fix this, you need to open a separate terminal window
>   and run minikube tunnel. This configures networking routes such that
>   you have unique IP addresses assigned to every service of type:
>   LoadBalancer. - Brendan Burns. “Kubernetes: Up and Running.”

I ran `minikube tunnel` in a seperate window but it still did not give me an `EXTERNAL-IP`.

How can I get this `EXTERNAL-IP` so I can point some hosts to it and test the ingress.

**Update**

I get all the services in the namespace and the `enoy` service has an external ip. I added those to `/etc/hosts` and it worked.

```
$ kubectl get -n projectcontour service -o wide
NAME      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE     SELECTOR
contour   ClusterIP      10.103.81.4     <none>          8001/TCP                     4d12h   app=contour
envoy     LoadBalancer   10.97.220.191   10.97.220.191   80:32162/TCP,443:31422/TCP   4d12h   app=envoy
```

**Update 2**:

Only where the `service.type = LoadBalancer` do you get an `externalIP`:

```
$ kubectl describe service envoy -n projectcontour
Name:                     envoy
Namespace:                projectcontour
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{"service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol":"tcp"},"nam...
                          service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: tcp
Selector:                 app=envoy
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.97.220.191
LoadBalancer Ingress:     10.97.220.191
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               80/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32162/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.17:80
Port:                     https  443/TCP
TargetPort:               443/TCP
NodePort:                 https  31422/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.17:443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Local
HealthCheck NodePort:     31511
Events:                   <none>
```

and:

```
$ kubectl describe service contour -n projectcontour
Name:              contour
Namespace:         projectcontour
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                     {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"contour","namespace":"projectcontour"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"...
Selector:          app=contour
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.103.81.4
Port:              xds  8001/TCP
TargetPort:        8001/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.13:8001,172.17.0.14:8001
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, I am stuck in a similar problem except that I see the external ip as "pending" and it doesn't change. Did u enable any ingress addon ? I had it enabled but turned it off.

Answer (score 2):

Your service type would need to be `LoadBalancer` to have an external-ip.

Comment: Do this by editing the service: `kubectl edit service contour -n projectcontour` and change line `type: ClusterIP` to `type: LoadBalancer`

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the service to loadbalancer

or just try and patch external IP

```
$ kubectl patch svc svc_name -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["your_external_ip"]}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever HttpProxy object you create, you will resolve it with envoy LoadBalancer ExternalIP. Envoy talks to contour internally to find out which service and port the traffic directs to. So, contour should not be exposed to a LoadBalancer. Hence, it does not have any ExternalIP.